# How to retrieve count from text file and sort by the maximum number then display it on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files

Here's my text file:

```
['hello', 'sffr', '18/08/2019 21:36:43', '1']
['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 18:23:15', '1']
['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 19:53:15', '2']
```

I am trying to retrieve the number in the final column by inputting a string that matches the word in first column. If there are any entries with the same name, I want to return the highest number out of all those entries.

Here is my main script:

```
import csv


word = input('\nAdd a word: ')

sorted_dates = []
with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(readFile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")

    for i, line in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
        if not line:
            continue

        if word in line[0]:
            sorted_dates.extend(line[3][-3])
            highestCount = max(sorted_dates)

            print(sorted_dates)
```

When I type the word "bye", it returns:

```
['1']
['1','2']
```

Instead, I would like to return the maximum value out of those:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `sorted_dates` in the loop.

One option is to just `print(max(sorted_dates)` outside the loop (`highestCount` isn't needed for this example).

If you enter `bye` when prompted, your result will be the desired `2`.

history.txt:

```
['hello', 'sffr', '18/08/2019 21:36:43', '1']

['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 18:23:15', '1']

['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 19:53:15', '2']
```

Code:

```py
import csv

word = input('\nAdd a word: ')

sorted_dates = []
with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(readFile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")

    for i, line in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
        if not line:
            continue

        if word in line[0]:
            sorted_dates.extend(line[3][-3])
            # highestCount = max(sorted_dates)

print(max(sorted_dates))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is `json.loads`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
import json
from pathlib import Path


word = input('\nAdd a word: ')

sorted_dates = []
fname = 'history.txt'
ss = Path(fname).read_text().splitlines()

for line in ss:
    if not line:
        continue
    data = json.loads(line.replace("'", '"'))
    if word == data[0]:
        sorted_dates.append(data[-1])
        highest_count = max(sorted_dates)

print(f'{sorted_dates = }')
print(f'{highest_count = }')
```